# PostgreSQL exact match with full text search

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How can I search rows that match search phrase? If search query is **funny dog**

I need to get result, where searching field contains **ONLY** these 2 words "funny" and "dog" in any order, in any word form (dogs, funnier, funniest...) and skipping prepositions and articles (a, the, and, of...)

Comment: Just a guess:   SELECT headername FROM myDatabase WHERE headername = '*dog*' or headername " '*gentle*'.          EDIT: seems the wildchar signes disepeared. Test wrapping dog and gentle with  *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the english stemmer which PostgreSQL uses does not stem comparatives and superlatives (I have to think that that is by design and not just by mistake) there is no reasonable way to do this in PostgreSQL out of the box.

```
select to_tsvector('english','funny funnier funniest big bigger biggest');
                            to_tsvector                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 'big':4 'bigger':5 'biggest':6 'funni':1 'funnier':2 'funniest':3
```

But if you install the [english_hunspell dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY) (not itself trivial) then you can get closer to what you want, at least for the one example you give.

```
create text search configuration english_hun (copy = english);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION english_hun alter mapping replace english_stem with english_hunspell;
select to_tsvector('english_hun','funny funnier funniest big bigger biggest');
                 to_tsvector                  
----------------------------------------------
 'big':4 'bigger':5 'biggest':6 'funny':1,2,3
```

The most common prepositions are already stop words, but not all of them so you might need to tweak your stop-word list.

After doing the usual match (@@) you could than add an AND condition making sure the length of the tsvector and tsquery are the same.  This would match 'funny dog funny', which it is not clear to me if you want or not.

Comment: Thankyou. Is there any options to make tsquery exact match tsvector? Not partial, as it works with @@ operator. Something like equality comparing tsquery to rsvector, not like.

Comment: I don't think so.  'strip' will remove positional indicators from a tsvector, but also remove any indication of how many times each token appeared.  So I think you would need to implement something yourself if you don't want 'funny dog funny' to match.  It shouldn't be all that hard in plpython or plperl, just a bit tedious to get all the quoting and escaping correct.

Comment: This is a real bummer. Any reason why they do that? I was hoping to be able to use PG instead of ElasticSearch, at least for a little while

Comment: It doesn't explicitly store a count. If 7 positions are listed, that means it occured 7 times.  If you remove the positions, you implicitly remove the count.  So removing the counts is not intentional.  Out of curiousity, how do you get elasticsearch to do what you want?

Comment: @jjanes I'm playing around with ElasticSearch now and it doesn't seem to work either, actually. Looks like I will retry Postgres.