# Why Doesn't This Full Text Search Match in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, stemming

I'm evaluating PostgreSQL to see if it is a viable alternative for ElasticSearch to begin with (migrating later is fine). I've been reading that PG full text capability is now 'good enough'. I'm running version 11.

Why doesn't this detect a match? I thought stemming would have easily detected different forms of the word "big":

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'bigger') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'big')
```

Am I using the wrong configuration?

Comment: It looks like neither of them is "stemmed" to the same base word: `select ts_debug('english', 'big') , ts_debug('english', 'bigger')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, l've just posted an answer. I'm surprised this isn't available out of the box. It requires a separate dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also reuse the scripts **english.sh** and **english.sql** from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57058/how-do-i-use-an-ispell-dictionary-with-postgres-text-search.

I have modified in the generated dictionaries:
in **english.affix** I have added the IG > GER rule:

```
flag *R:
    E           >       R               # As in skate > skater
    [^AEIOU]Y   >       -Y,IER          # As in multiply > multiplier
    [AEIOU]Y    >       ER              # As in convey > conveyer
    [^EY]       >       ER              # As in build > builder
    IG          >       GER             # For big > bigger
```

in **english.dict** I have modified

```
big/PY
```

to

```
big/PYR
```

After running english.sql for the current database (you need to modify database name in the script):

```
postgres=# select ts_debug('english bigger');
select ts_debug('english bigger');
                                              ts_debug                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",english,"{english_ispell,english_stem}",english_ispell,{english})
 (blank,"Space symbols"," ",{},,)
 (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",bigger,"{english_ispell,english_stem}",english_ispell,"{bigger,big}")
(3 rows)

postgres=# SELECT to_tsvector('english bigger') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'big');
SELECT to_tsvector('english bigger') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'big');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Were you able to get those dictionary files to download in that link? Says they aren't found for me.

Comment: Yes the link http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/tars/ispell-3.4.00.tar.gz worked yesterday and is still workding today.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to install an ispell dictionary as the English dictionary doesn't do this by default.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61213187/148390